# Python requests module - no module found

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I have a chat box on my website and i want to add messages with a python script using the `requests` library.

The script looks like this:

```
import requests
import os
import random
import string
import json

random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

url = 'http://subdomain.example.com/dir/filename.php'
names = json.loads(open('dir/filename.json').read())
messages = ['heyy', 'hoi', 'hai', 'he', 'haai', 'heyyy', 'hooi', 'heey', 'hee', 'hey', 'hallo']

for name in names:
    username = name.lower()
    message = random.choice(messages)
    params={
        'username': username,
        'message': message
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=params)
```

When I run the script in the command prompt it returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dir/filename.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

When I google this problem I find that I need to install requests. I already did with pip like this:

```
pip install requests
```

When I tried to install requests again to be sure it responded:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\usern\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2018.8.13)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: You probably have several versions of Python installed, and `pip` doesn't default to the one you try to execute the script with.

Comment: Are you using a IDE like pycharm?  you can try to install the requirement through IDE

Comment: are you running it in an virtual env. Try pip freeze to list of installed package before runing the script

Comment: I am with DeepSpace. Check that Python version that you are running when execute the script is the same Python version that you have installed in C:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had the script located in my localhost.(not where python is installed) I moved the file to C:/python34 ans the script did what was needed.